# ASP.NET: Table with Repeater control and alternating data in same for

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have an assignment to move one of our pages from a single table with three columns, into two table which display the same data set but squeezed together and alternated. So if my data set today is displayed as

[image]

The new data set would look like 
[image]

So far, I can get the table data to alternate, but I can't then start a new row.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="fruitRep" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr align="center">
                    <th>Line</th>
                    <th>Fruit</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>    
                    <th class ="ghostColumn">Blank</th>    
                    <th>Line</th>
                    <th>Fruit</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
                <td><%= LineCounter %></td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, Fruit")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, PerUnitCost")%> 
                </td>
                <td class ="ghostColumn">...</td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <td><%= LineCounter %></td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, Fruit")%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, PerUnitCost")%> 
                </td>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the headers and the items in the same table, you can do this. Use `Container.ItemIndex %2 == 0` to write the start or end of a row.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Line</th>
        <th>Fruit</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Line</th>
        <th>Fruit</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>

    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <%# Container.ItemIndex %2 == 0 ? "<tr>" : "" %>

            <td><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Ride_id") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("naam") %></td>

            <%# Container.ItemIndex %2 == 0 ? "<td></td>" : "</tr>" %>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it will still need some styling, your code could be as simple as that:

```
<!-- you'll have to create the column headers outside the DataList -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Line</td><td>Fruit</td><td>Cost</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Line</td><td>Fruit</td><td>Cost</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<asp:DataList ID="fruitRep" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></td>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Fruit") %></td>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PerUnitCost") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>&nbsp;</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Note that I fudged in the table cells into the enclosing ItemTemplate which itself creates a starting and closing table cell.